# Solr: Group by and select max n rows using collapse and expand

Tags: xml, solr

I have below document in `Solr`

```
    

 <doc>
        <str name="guid">2b490ceeee24bfd1ca227acca4a3be1e</str>
        <long name="Size">224945</long>
        <str name="Name">Solr1.log</str>
     </doc>
     <doc>
        <str name="guid">381fd57f1d7b9d810252cf879323c14d</str>
        <long name="Size">224945</long>
        <str name="Name">Solr2.log</str>
     </doc>
     <doc>
        <str name="guid">722f7d24b9e67a21ab31844465e6b258</str>
        <long name="Size">224945</long>
        <str name="Name">Solr3.log</str>
     </doc>
     <doc>
        <str name="guid">27a7e20c253f6e4d633f2aaf2bb59d55</str>
        <long name="Size">224945</long>
        <str name="Name">Solr4.log</str>
     </doc>
     <doc>
        <str name="guid">e45ea4ce0763f2d0284794d1d59c6a35</str>
        <long name="Size">224945</long>
        <str name="Name">Solr5.log</str>
     </doc>
     <doc>
        <str name="guid">2b490ceeee24bfd1ca227acca4a3be1e</str>
        <long name="Size">224945</long>
        <str name="Name">Solr6.log</str>
     </doc>
     <doc>
        <str name="guid">2b490ceeee24bfd1ca227acca4a3be1e</str>
        <long name="Size">224945</long>
        <str name="Name">Solr7.log</str>
     </doc>
     <doc>
        <str name="guid">381fd57f1d7b9d810252cf879323c14d</str>
        <long name="Size">224945</long>
        <str name="Name">Solr8.log</str>
     </doc>
```

Using collapse/expand I want to group the rows by guid and select only maximum first 2 rows from each group. So my result would become

```
 

<doc>
    <str name="guid">2b490ceeee24bfd1ca227acca4a3be1e</str>
    <long name="Size">224945</long>
    <str name="Name">Solr1.log</str>
 </doc>
 <doc>
    <str name="guid">381fd57f1d7b9d810252cf879323c14d</str>
    <long name="Size">224945</long>
    <str name="Name">Solr2.log</str>
 </doc>
 <doc>
    <str name="guid">722f7d24b9e67a21ab31844465e6b258</str>
    <long name="Size">224945</long>
    <str name="Name">Solr3.log</str>
 </doc>
 <doc>
    <str name="guid">27a7e20c253f6e4d633f2aaf2bb59d55</str>
    <long name="Size">224945</long>
    <str name="Name">Solr4.log</str>
 </doc>
 <doc>
    <str name="guid">e45ea4ce0763f2d0284794d1d59c6a35</str>
    <long name="Size">224945</long>
    <str name="Name">Solr5.log</str>
 </doc>
 <doc>
    <str name="guid">2b490ceeee24bfd1ca227acca4a3be1e</str>
    <long name="Size">224945</long>
    <str name="Name">Solr6.log</str>
 </doc>
 <doc>
    <str name="guid">381fd57f1d7b9d810252cf879323c14d</str>
    <long name="Size">224945</long>
    <str name="Name">Solr8.log</str>
 </doc>
```

This is what I tried but this does not seem to be working

```
{!collapse field=guid sort='Sizedesc'}&expand=true&expand.rows=2
```